# Python and string literal to execute command for "git log" filtering

Tags: python, git

I have a python script which executes `bash` commands on the linux server. Name of the method is `exec_cmd` and it worked perfectly, until now.
I need to execute `git log` command on the linux server which returns one specific git commit.
`git log --grep="\[AccuRev transaction: 14126178\]"`

Output:

```
`commit a176c1e534735b7b8b6506730288a62c3f2754cb    
Author: ....    
Date:   ...    
    [AccuRev transaction: 14126178]`
```

You will notice that `git log` command must have backslash when executing it on the server.

In python I tried with my `exec_cmd` function which works for any other git command but with this command that includes `"` and `\` it doesn't work. Output is EMPTY.

`exec_cmd(['git', 'log', r'--grep="\[AccuRev transaction: 14126178\]"'], fail=True)`

As you see I tried with `stringprefix` string literal  `r` but without luck.

In log I can see it executed like this this:
`['git', 'log', '--grep="\\[AccuRev transaction: 14126178\\]"']`

I had an issue with similar command for `git checkout` that I resolved in python and the difference is that it didn't included quotes in it.

`git checkout -b mynewbranch1 ':/\[AccuRev transaction: 21114530\]'`

And in python code, the solution that worked was this:

`exec_cmd(['git', 'checkout', '-b', "branch1", r':/\[AccuRev transaction: ' +str(transaction_id)+'\]'], fail=True)`

What should be corrected in the  `git log` python code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The double quotes are wrong, you need them for the shell but here, there is no shell.

Comment: Yah, the way you've got it coded here Git's looking for literal quotes. Lose them. When the shell is parsing command lines it does one layer of preprocessing, `$` introduces parameter expansion but the marker is discarded, double quotes shut off wordsplitting and globbing but the quotes are discarded, single quotes shut off *everything* and then the quotes are discarded, and so on.